# I am trying to Create TexttoSpeech in NET 5 core. for this,swagger UI is not showing anything in webapi

Tags: c#, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to Create TexttoSpeech in NET 5 core. For this. When i run my project in Browser. Somehow swagger UI is not showing anything , I have created a Model called Speech Model and Index.chtml page and a interface in startup class.

namespace TextToSpeechApp.Model
{
public class SpeechModel
{
public string Content { get; set; }

```
    public string SubscriptionKey { get; set; } = "< Subscription Key >";

    [DisplayName("Language Selection :")]
    public string LanguageCode { get; set; } = "NA";

    public List<SelectListItem> LanguagePreference { get; set; } = new List<SelectListItem>
    {
    new SelectListItem { Value = "NA", Text = "-Select-" },
    new SelectListItem { Value = "en-US", Text = "English (United States)"  },
    new SelectListItem { Value = "en-IN", Text = "English (India)"  },
    new SelectListItem { Value = "ta-IN", Text = "Tamil (India)"  },
    new SelectListItem { Value = "hi-IN", Text = "Hindi (India)"  },
    new SelectListItem { Value = "te-IN", Text = "Telugu (India)"  }
    };

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have not created any API endpoints in your project. Check out this complete guide on NET Core API and adding Swagger UI to it: [Swagger in ASP.Net Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Once you create HTTP endpoints (`GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, etc.), you will be able to see API definitions Out of the Box in Swagger page.

Comment: Thanks for helping out! It still doesn't seems to working out. here is code for startup:

Comment: looks like link is for Asp.Net core 2.2 ,I am using Asp.Net core 5.  have installed Swashbuckle.AspNetCore as well.

Comment: and using IIS express

Comment: Yes, I have added Ms docs links for you. Pls check it out and keep the code same as that. Make sire you add endpoints in your ApiController for it to work.

Comment: not yet, got error . Failed to load API definition.Fetch error
Internal Server Error /swagger/v1/swagger.json

Comment: Ok, did you implement API code mentioned in the link I shared?

Comment: Yes, I did implement API code , Your magic works now for  default swagger. Thanks. How do I see content of the index page that  I created as per above . It is still not showing output for TextToSpeechapp. Can I get your email ? is it possible if I can send the project for review?

Comment: What does it show? Pls share the screenshot. I will share email once if deep look into your issue is required.

Comment: @singh-msft Thanks for help!  When you get a moment ,Can you review the code. Here is Github link,  https://github.com/dotnetexpo/TextToSpeechAPP